# How many transactions are there when many threads read the some location in the global memory at the same time?

Tags: multithreading, opencl

I am writing a kernel where all the threads would be launched and read the same location in the global memory at the same time. 
I was wondering what would happen at this time? 
Did the value in the global memory broadcast to all the threads or is there
any sort of serialization?

I knew when half of the warp threads access fits into the same segment of the global memory, the access would be coalesced into fewer transactions.
But what would happen when reading the exact same location?
If it is broadcast, does it mean not any more optimization would be required here?

I am using AMD 7470 here. And I wrote an iteration where all the threads would read the same 4 Bytes in the global memory in each iteration.

Comment: I am using AMD 7470 here, and I wrote an iteration where each iteration would read 4 Bytes in the global memory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most GPUs broadcast the same-location read to all work items. It's mentioned specifically in the optimization guides.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you want to read the global memory location(s) as few time as posisble per workgroup. This means you should copy it into local memory and further reads should be directed at the locally cached data.

I find this is more commonly done with blocks of data larger than just 4 bytes, but there should be a time savings as long as you are avoiding many global reads.

```
local int sharedInt;
int id = get_local_id(0);
if(id == 0){
sharedInt = globalVar;
}
barrier(); //or barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE) if the compiler complains
```

Now you are gauranteed that the global data was read only once per work group.

This method should work on all device types. I believe that it forces the lowest cache level on a CPU, but that would be implementation-dependent.

Comment: For only 4 bytes, it is probably a bad idea to do this. It is much more useful on a larger amount of data -- a few KB at least.